# Detecting MP3 support in a page for old browser

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, sniffer

I'm writing an mp3 playlist player, and I'm almost done... but, I would like to make the page compatible with older browser (people with older browsers will see a simple list of mp3 links: they can download them, it's not a problem).
Now, I'm afraid I have some problem with javascript syntax, rather than with some specific command.
So, this is my code:

```js
ilikemp3 = 0;

if (document.createElement('audio').canPlayType('audio/mpeg;codecs="mp3"'))
{ilikemp3 = 1};

if (ilikemp3)
{audio_playlist_html5()}
else
{simple_audio_list()};
```

It's working fine on modern browsers... but, if I run it in older browsers, I get an error message:

Error: document.createElement("audio").canPlayType is not a function

So, I understand that's not the proper way to query a browser.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the existence of `canPlayType` in `document.createElement('audio')` and decide based on that.

```js
if('canPlayType' in document.createElement('audio')) {
  //new player
}
else {
  //old player
}
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSS!!!
It's working!!!
Thanks you so much... you're great!

Comment: This isn't a good solution... or is at least incomplete.  Old browsers on major platforms were able to decode MP3 just fine, even without `canPlayType` support.  The only way to really check it is to try to play and see what happens.

Comment: @Brad Would you mind elaborating more? My answer is specific to the question OP is asking given the information provided. I'm assuming the better route would be to try/catch `audio_playlist_html5()` and fall back to `simple_audio_list()` when it throws?

Comment: The `Audio` object is still going to get created, even if the browser can't necessarily play the file with the particular codec.  What I would do is simply handle the `error` event of that audio element, and when it happens, show the alternative list.  If the user goes to play, and play doesn't work for whatever reason, the downloads can still occur.